# PyQt app crashes on exit (Python 3.4.3 / PyQt5 / Windows 10)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I realize this is a bit of a vague question, but I'm not sure how to make it more specific.

The skeleton for my code is below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *

class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        form = FormWidget(self) 
        self.setCentralWidget(form) 

        [do a bunch of stuff with form]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Within the FormWidget class, there is a keyPressEvent() method that traps keyboard input, and on a specific key ('q'), calls this:

```
mainWindow.close()
```

Most of the time, that causes the app to exit, as desired.  But occasionally (with no predictable pattern that I can discern), it causes a crash (dialog comes up that says 'python.exe has stopped working', with a 'Close program' button).

First question, I guess, is:  Is this not the proper way to terminate a PyQt GUI app?

If it is, then second question is:  Presumably, my code is misbehaving somewhere.  But I'm not sure what sort of misbehavior to be looking for.  What sort of mistake could I be making that would cause this?

Any thoughts appreciated.

/John

Comment: This is a well known issue that has many different potential causes. You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the problem with reasonable reliability. The most likely cause is that you are failing to keep a reference to some object, and things are being deleted in the wrong order (due to the inherent randomness of python's gc on exit).

Comment: Thanks ... this should be helpful.  I certainly would have posted an MCVE that reproduced the problem reliably, if I could find one.  As it stands, the problem I think could be anywhere in the code.  If I'd been smart, I'd have paid closer attention to what code I just added when the problem began to occur ... but I wasn't that smart.  :-(

That's why my question was so vague.  I was hoping for something like "That tends to happen when you do X", so I could go through the code and try to find places where I've done X.  Your answer gave me a place to start.