# PyQt app crashes on exit (Python 3.4.3 / PyQt5 / Windows 10) [follow-up]

Tags: python, pyqt5

(This is a follow-up to a question from a couple days ago.  I couldn't decide which was best -- editing the original question, following up with a comment, or posting a new question.  I went with the last ...)

Previously, I posted about an app which crashes when PyQt exits [[PyQt app crashes on exit (Python 3.4.3 / PyQt5 / Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330129/pyqt-app-crashes-on-exit-python-3-4-3-pyqt5-windows-10]), which I've since discovered is a rather common problem.  It was suggested I try to provide an MCVE.  Here's the smallest I could pare it down to:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *


# ======================================================================
# | Class:  Form
# |
# |
# ======================================================================
class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initializations
        self.initForm()

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------
    # | initForm()
    # |
    # | Create new form object
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------
    def initForm(self):

        # Main horizontal layout
        self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Left vertical layout -- image view and display
        self.left_vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.image = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("Audubon.jpg"))
        self.image.setScale(2.0)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addItem(self.image)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.left_vlayout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.display = QLabel()                                 # [1]
        self.left_vlayout.addWidget(self.display)               #

        # Right vertical layout -- name edit, movement controls
        self.right_vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.name = QLineEdit()
        self.right_vlayout.addWidget(self.name)
        self.controls_layout = QGridLayout()                    # [2]
        self.right_vlayout.addLayout(self.controls_layout)      #

        # Add left and right vertical layouts to horizontal layout, and set it for form
        self.hlayout.addLayout(self.left_vlayout)
        self.hlayout.addLayout(self.right_vlayout)
        self.setLayout(self.hlayout)


    # ------------------------------------------------------------------
    # | keyPressEvent()
    # |
    # | Process keyboard input
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        mod = int(event.modifiers())                            # [3]

        if key == Qt.Key_Q:
            mainWindow.close()


# ======================================================================
# | Class:  MainWindow
# |
# |
# ======================================================================
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        form = FormWidget(self) 
        self.setCentralWidget(form) 
        self.resize(1750, 700)
        self.move(50, 300)


# ======================================================================
# | Main
# |
# |
# ======================================================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import time

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle("MCVE")
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Using a tool called AutoIt, I wrote an automation script to test the code.  The script runs the code 100 times, each time starting it, then immediately passing a 'q' character to quit.

As shown above, the code will always crash when exiting, sometime within 100 runs (usually within the first dozen or two).

If I make any of these changes (individually, not all at once):

- Comment out the two lines labeled [1]
- Comment out the two lines labeled [2]
- Comment out the line labeled [3] (this one surprised me)

then the code consistently runs 100 times in a row, without crashing on exit.

I've pored over the code, but I can't see anything wrong.  In particular, I can't see anything special about the three groups of code which, when commented out, cause it to run properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks again.
/John

Comment: I don't have time to test this at the moment, but the fact you are using a `QGraphicsScene` stands out straight away. When you set a scene on a view, Qt does not take ownership of it. So it is always prudent to give the scene a parent.

Comment: I tried changing the line that assigns the QGraphicsScene object to `self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)`.  But it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Try also adding: `mainWindow.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)`. I am unable to induce a crash on linux, and can't test on windows, so it's difficult to narrow the issue down any further. It would seem likely that commenting out the lines you mention just changes the order in which objects are deleted, and so is not really diagnostic.

Comment: Empirically, your second suggestion seems to solve the problem, with or without your first suggestion (giving the scene a parent).  Also, If I move the keyPressEvent() method from the FormWidget class to the MainWindow class (and then call `self.close()` instead of `mainWindow.close()`), the problem seems to disappear (even in the absence of your suggested changes).  Of course, any of these solutions could just be changing the gc order, like my random commenting out of lines.  But the current changes sort of "feel right".  (Maybe I should try sacrificing a chicken, too).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Now as I think about it:  In the code as I originally posted it, where keyPressEvent() is defined as a method of the FormWidget class, why is the statement `mainWindow.close()` even valid?  I'm surprised `mainWindow` is even accessible there.  Indeed, if I try to refer to `mainWindow` in FormWidget's other methods (e.g., `initForm()`), I get an interpreter error `mainWindow is not defined`.

Comment: The `mainWindow` variable is `global`. It isn't be available in `__init__`, because it won't be assigned to until the function returns. As for the original problem: both the changes I suggested are considered good "housekeeping", even if they do not appear to solve any immediate problems. However, there is no 100% guarantee that they will always work: there is really no universal solution that can do that (as things currently stand).

Comment: No.  Alas, I added all the changes to my original app, and it still intermittently crashes on exit.  Not as frequently, seemingly, but not never.  :-(

Comment: Just because there's no *universal* solution doesn't mean you can't solve it for your particular application, so I wouldn't give up. What you need to aim for in general, is to have a single root widget (usually the main window), with all other widgets/objects as descendants of it. This arrangement maximises the chances that Qt can recursively delete all the internal C++ parts in the right order before the python gc starts sweeping up the remaining python parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103357/discussion-between-jfsturtz-and-ekhumoro).